# 2008 Mazda Tribute brake pedal very soft

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting, mazda

2008 Mazda Tribute brake pedal goes to floor. I have bled the brakes, installed a new master cylinder and power booster and new front pads. I had a scan done and was told it is the power booster sensor. I can not find anything about the power booster sensor. Are they talking about the two switches on the brake pedal?

Comment: Welcome to the site. How confident are you that there is no air in the brake lines?

Comment: mechanic did yesterday

Comment: Any chance it's the brake booster check valve?

Comment: What engine? Hybrid? AWD?

Comment: No. Had it checked yesterday and was told it shows as brake booster sensor and mine does not have one, and that the dealer will need to reset computer, unless someone can tell me how to reset computer as I have looked online and no info for 08 Mazda tribute 3.0L FWD. Thank You